# how to get method argument list from mangled name?

Tags: java

I have following information in cobertura.xml

```
<method name="visitNode"
        signature="(Lchs/cof/drawplus/IJoint;Lchs/cof/logical/schem/ISegment;Lchs/analysis/GraphServices$IGraphVisitor;I)Z"
```

The signature is java's mangled name for the method. (http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q7)

How can I construct the method argumentlist, which was like below.

```
 boolean visitNode(drawplus.IJoint root,
            schem.ISegment segmentBefore,
            IGraphVisitor visitor,
            int branch)
```

Is there a library which can do this de-mangling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the types of the arguments and result from the method descriptor, but you can't extract the parameter names.

I don't know of a library that will do this extraction, though I'm sure this code has been implemented a few times.  It is not difficult to implement yourself.  The syntax of a method descriptor string is specified in the Java Virtual Machine Specification - [JVMS 4.3.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#7035).

Comment: I agree. Using another library may be overkill.

Comment: @Jayan - I wouldn't necessarily say it was overkill ... if you could find a library that provided a simple API to do this.  I'm just pointing out that it is not a great issue if you need to write your own code to do it.

Comment: FWIW the parameter names are available in the LocalVariableTable. As alluded to in Erik's answer, this is only usually present in classes compiled with debug information (`javac -g` and similar).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a reproduction of the mangling rules, as this question comes up quite high on search results for this topic. Details below are from the link in the original question.

Primitive representations:

- `V` - `void`
- `Z` - `boolean`
- `C` - `char`
- `B` - `byte`
- `S` - `short`
- `I` - `int`
- `F` - `float`
- `J` - `long`
- `D` - `double`

Class representations:

- `L<class>;`
- `Ljava/io/ObjectOutput;`
- `Ljava/lang/String;`

Answer (score 2):

[JD Core](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) should do all this for you. However, it's a c++ lib so it might not be applicable to you. 
[BCEL (Byte Code Engineering Library](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/index.html) allows you to create, analyze and modify binary files which should be something along the lines of what you want. BCEL is written in java.
If the class files is not compiled with the debug flag, then the parameter names might be generic.